# How do i replace the dots in my table of contents between the text and page number with a horizontal line using the tocstyle package?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocstyle

Due to some major design changes in our corporate identity, its now up to me to update our existing latex document class according to the new design guidelines.
I´m having troubles cutomizing the layout of our table of contents. Instead of filling the gaps between sections and page numbers with dots, I need to use a continuous horizonal line.

Thus, instead of

Chapter...............................................................1

I need

Chapter__________________________________________1

How can this be achieved using the tocstyle package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature is documented in table 3 of the manual:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\settocfeature{leaders}{\ \leaders\hrule\hfill}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\section{Sec}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could exchange the dots with an underscore and change the separation lower than zero with the tocloft package.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\_}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{-.5}
```

It looks a bit like a quick and dirty solution, especially since the gap between section name and underscore is too small.

Answer (score 0):

The other upvoted answer didn't compile for me. Instead I went with this:

```tex
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{ \hrulefill}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{ \hrulefill}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{ \hrulefill}
```

Which replaces the fill method in the leaders with an hrulefill (preceded by a space).

[image]